# GroupBy in Immutable.js and then return first value of grouped List

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Is it possible in Immutable.js to `groupBy()` a value, say `id`, and then inside the `map()` basically take the first value of the group append a new property to it and then return that single item? If not, does anyone have a suggestion on how to make this work?

```
    fromJS([  {'id':1, 'x':2},
      {'id':2, 'x':3},
      {'id':2, 'x':4}
    ])
    .groupBy(item => item.get('id'))
    .map(values => {
        let item = values.first();
        return item.merge({
            xs: values.map(d => d.get('x'))
        })
    });
    // expected output as a List() - 
      [
       {'id':1, 'x':2, 'xs': [2]},
       {'id':2, 'x':3, 'xs': [3, 4]}
      ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can `groupBy` id and you are actually very close to the solution you want, but missing the `.toArray()`.

```js
var out = Immutable.fromJS([
  {'id':1, 'x':2},
  {'id':2, 'x':3},
  {'id':2, 'x':4}
])
.groupBy(item => item.get('id'))
.map(values => {
  let item = values.first();
  return item.merge({
    xs: values.map(d => d.get('x'))
  });
}).toArray();

console.log(JSON.stringify(out));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.js"></script>
```

The jsfiddle is also available here: https://fiddle.jshell.net/rguf75fc/

Comment: I think you may want [`.toList()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/toList) and not `.toArray()`.